# Alternative to chrome.storage.sync that can store more than 8kb in a key

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I built a chrome extension that takes information from a popup form, formats that in a certain way, and spits out that "card". See below for a picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkDU0.png

When it spits out the seperate "cards", it saves the innerHTML of the div containing all of the cards to storage. When the program loads, it takes that item from storage and changes the innerHTML of the div accordingly to what was saved. That way, when I refresh or exit and come back, the cards do not disapear.

However, I've ran into some problems because I intend to use this program on multiple computers, but I do not want to have different cards on one computer than I have another.

My goal: Be able to save two strings (likely massive in size, far exceeding 8kb) across multiple computers.

What I've tried:

- I've attempted to use local.storage and chrome.local.storage but each do not provide the capability for use across multiple computers.
- I've tried to use chrome.sync which showed the best possibility of success, but failed because there is a strict 8kb quota for keys and my keys are much larger than 8kb because they save the entire div.
- Researching a way to store the strings in like google drive or something. I found some API that I think did similar but it was deprecated.
- Looking for an exterior way to store data but I believe they all cost money.

Code:

```
function setOnLocalStorage(){
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'template': document.getElementById('cards').innerHTML})
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'groupTemplate': document.getElementById('listContainer').innerHTML})

chrome.storage.sync.get('template', function(data){   
    var z = data
    document.getElementById('cards').innerHTML = [Object.values(z)[0]]
    })

chrome.storage.sync.get('groupTemplate', function(data){   
    var y = data
    document.getElementById('listContainer').innerHTML = [Object.values(y)[0]]
    })
```

Other information:
Each of the cards of seperate divs, if that helps.
I have delete and copy functions on each card avaiable through an altered context menu.

Comment: Seems 8kb is huge as cookie limit is 4kb. If data is huge then it would not easy to update it.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm confused on what you mean? When I used localStorage for the data it worked ok because local storage byte limit is like 5 million. Is there no alternative for more than 8kb?

Comment: You're right. local storage has 5Mb limit.

Comment: The thing is sharing 8kb string within multiple machines. I got it now.

Comment: Yeah, my issue arises at the fact that chrome sync as described by google is a bunch of little tubes, not a truck. Unfortunately, I need a truck. Wondering if there is an alternative or way to manipulate chrome sync to work the way I intend.

Comment: Is hall data changed? I mean only data changed should be shared by `chrome.storage.sync` because tags don't have to be shared as these are just forms. It's not an answer but an opinion. :)

Comment: Hope you can find the way. For now, seems using a server for sharing a bunch of data only works.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion! :)  Only the content of the card is changed per card. (and highlight color). So none of the style tags. However, because I use a copy button, the styles need to be inline so they will be copied. I hope there’s another solution besides a server. I only really need to transport 2 strings and I want to avoid having to use a server for that.

Comment: So only the content of the card is changed but styles are not! But is there any reason that you don't add `.css` file or `<style>` tag in your popup HTML file? I hope there is a solution without using server too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value to be stored is a little above 8 Kb you can use a js library which shrink the content (zip).
You can also implement a tailored routine that splits the value in more smaller than 8kb keys and joins that keys when you'll need to retrieve the original value.
You can merge these two approaches together or...
...you can use supabase or firebase services.

Comment: I’ll definitely mark this as the right answer! I just have a few questions if you wouldn’t mind answering. I love the idea about the zip. Which library do you recommend? Should I just pick one and it doesn’t matter? On the tailored routine, is this anywhere you know where I can find an example of how to split up the keys? And regarding fire base, is it possible to link data to a specific google account? Maybe like through oAuth2 and getting the email of the user?

Comment: I wouldn't know to suggest a particolar zip library. There are several. I've tried one some month ago and I found it very slow (but I had to shrink about 100Mb). A split-and-join key routine shouldn't be so hard to code. I'm pretty sure to have read something similar in stackoverflow. For your last question, you can link data stored in supabase with google account using chrome identity API.

Comment: Note that storage.Sync also has other limits (over 8kbytes per key).
I do not remember the numbers, but I know there are memorization limits at the level of extension and\or profile.
Check these values well before starting to work there, I don't think it is allowed to store over a couple of megabytes in total (perhaps even less)

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I’m going to go with a database like Firebase like you suggested. Time to go figure out the identity API. I really appreciate your help.